# Calcuting the date difference for a specified number of days using LocalDate class

Tags: java, localdate, threetenbp

I'm using openjdk version **1.8.0_112-release** for development but will need to support previous JDK versions too (pre-Java-8) - so can't use `java.time`.

I am writing a utitily class to calculate the date to see if a saved date is before the current date which means its expired.

However, I am not sure I have done this the correct way. I am using `LocalDate` class to calculate the days. The expiration is counted starting from the date and time the user clicked save. That date will be saved and a check will be done against this saved date and time and the current date and time i.e. when the user logs in.

Is this the best way to do it? I would like to keep to the `LocalDate` class.

```
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;

public final class Utilities {
    private Utilities() {}

    public static boolean hasDateExpired(int days, LocalDate savedDate, LocalDate currentDate) {
        boolean hasExpired = false;

        if(savedDate != null && currentDate != null) {
            /* has expired if the saved date plus the specified days is still before the current date (today) */
            if(savedDate.plusDays(days).isBefore(currentDate)) {
                hasExpired = true;
            }       
        }

        return hasExpired;
    }
}
```

I'm using the class like this:

```
private void showDialogToIndicateLicenseHasExpired() {
    final LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
    final int DAYS_TO_EXPIRE = 3;
    final LocalDate savedDate = user.getSavedDate();

    if(hasDateExpired(DAYS_TO_EXPIRE, savedDate, currentDate)) {
        /* License has expired, warn the user */    
    }
}
```

I am looking a solution that will take in account time zones. If a license was set to expire in 3 days, and the user was to travel to a different time zone. i.e. they could be ahead or behind based on hours. The license should still expire.

Comment: If you're using java 8, you don't need to use `org.threeten.bp`, you can use `java.time.LocalDate` class

Comment: As Hugo says, org.threeten.bp is from the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. That library back-ports much of the java.time functionality to Java 6 & Java 7. No need for the back-port in Java 8 and Java 9 as java.time is built-in.

Comment: So please, when exactly should the expiration happen? Is that simply 72 hours after save time (3 * 24 = 72)? Or not until midnight? Say user clicked save on 26 May 11:30 am, should expiration then be at midnight between 29 May and 30 May in the time zone where data was saved? Or, third option, on the same clock time 3 days later? This last may occasionally give you 71 or 73 hours on the transistion to or from summer time (daylight saving time).

Comment: @OleV.V. Reading your comment it should be 72 hours from the time that the user saved the date. So midnight should be ignored as we are counting down the hours.

Comment: don't write your own timezone code, use a library https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ChronoUnit.DAYS` (in `org.threeten.bp.temporal` package, or in `java.time.temporal` if you use java 8 native classes) to calculate the number of days between the 2 `LocalDate` objects:

```
if (savedDate != null && currentDate != null) {
    if (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(savedDate, currentDate) > days) {
        hasExpired = true;
    }
}
```

## Edit (after bounty explanation)

For this test, I'm using **threetenbp version 1.3.4**

As you want a solution that works even if the user is in a different timezone, you shouldn't use `LocalDate`, because this class doesn't handle timezone issues.

I think the best solution is to use the `Instant` class. It represents a single point in time, no matter in what timezone you are (at this moment, everybody in the world are in the same **instant**, although the **local date and time** might be different depending on where you are).

Actually `Instant` is always in [UTC Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html) - a standard **indepedent** of timezone, so very suitable to your case (as you want a calculation independent of what timezone the user is in).

So both your `savedDate` and `currentDate` must be `Instant`'s, and you should calculate the difference between them.

Now, a subtle detail. You want the expiration to happen after 3 days. For the code I did, I'm making the following assumptions:

- 3 days = 72 hours
- 1 fraction of a second after 72 hours, it's expired

The second assumption is important for the way I implemented the solution. I'm considering the following cases:

1. `currentDate` is less than 72 hours after `savedDate` - **not expired**
2. `currentDate` is exactly 72 hours after `savedDate` - **not expired** (or expired? see comments below)
3. `currentDate` is more than 72 hours after `savedDate` (even by a fraction of a second) - **expired**

The `Instant` class has nanosecond precision, so in case **3** I'm considering that it's expired even if it's 1 nanosecond after 72 hours:

```
import org.threeten.bp.Instant;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public static boolean hasDateExpired(int days, Instant savedDate, Instant currentDate) {
    boolean hasExpired = false;

    if (savedDate != null && currentDate != null) {
        // nanoseconds between savedDate and currentDate > number of nanoseconds in the specified number of days
        if (ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(savedDate, currentDate) > days * ChronoUnit.DAYS.getDuration().toNanos()) {
            hasExpired = true;
        }
    }

    return hasExpired;
}
```

Note that I used `ChronoUnit.DAYS.getDuration().toNanos()` to get the number of nanoseconds in a day. It's better to rely on the API instead of having hardcoded big error-prone numbers.

I've made some tests, using dates in the same timezone and in different ones.
I used `ZonedDateTime.toInstant()` method to convert the dates to `Instant`:

```
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneId;
import org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime;

// testing in the same timezone
ZoneId sp = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");
// savedDate: 22/05/2017 10:00 in Sao Paulo timezone
Instant savedDate = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 5, 22, 10, 0, 0, 0, sp).toInstant();
// 1 nanosecond before expires (returns false - not expired)
System.out.println(hasDateExpired(3, savedDate, ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 5, 25, 9, 59, 59, 999999999, sp).toInstant()));
// exactly 3 days (72 hours) after saved date (returns false - not expired)
System.out.println(hasDateExpired(3, savedDate, ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 5, 25, 10, 0, 0, 0, sp).toInstant()));
// 1 nanosecond after 3 days (72 hours) (returns true - expired)
System.out.println(hasDateExpired(3, savedDate, ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 5, 25, 10, 0, 0, 1, sp).toInstant()));

// testing in different timezones (savedDate in Sao Paulo, currentDate in London)
ZoneId london = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
// In 22/05/2017, London will be in summer time, so 10h in Sao Paulo = 14h in London
// 1 nanosecond before expires (returns false - not expired)
System.out.println(hasDateExpired(3, savedDate, ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 5, 25, 13, 59, 59, 999999999, london).toInstant()));
// exactly 3 days (72 hours) after saved date (returns false - not expired)
System.out.println(hasDateExpired(3, savedDate, ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 5, 25, 14, 0, 0, 0, london).toInstant()));
// 1 nanosecond after 3 days (72 hours) (returns true - expired)
System.out.println(hasDateExpired(3, savedDate, ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 5, 25, 14, 0, 0, 1, london).toInstant()));
```

---

**PS:** for case **2** *(`currentDate` is exactly 72 hours after savedDate - **not expired**)* - if you want this to be **expired**, just change the `if` above to use `>=` instead of `>`:

```
if (ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(savedDate, currentDate) >= days * ChronoUnit.DAYS.getDuration().toNanos()) {
    ... // it returns "true" for case 2
}
```

---

If you don't want nanosecond precision and just want to compare the days between the dates, you can do as in [@Ole V.V's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44208828/7605325). I believe our answers are very similar (and I **suspect** that the codes are equivalent, although I'm not sure), but I haven't tested enough cases to check if they differ in any particular situation.

Comment: I will have to keep with the org.threeten.bp.LocalDate as we have to support previous versions.

Comment: No problem, the code will basically be the same. Threeten is a backport and most functionality is implemented by it.

Comment: @ant2009 After seeing the bounty explanation (it must work in different timezones), I've updated the answer

Answer (score 10):

Your code is basically fine. I would do it basically the same way, just with a detail or two being different.

As Hugo has already noted, I would use `java.time.LocalDate` and drop the use of ThreeTen Backport (unless it is a specific requirement that your code can run on Java 6 or 7 too).

## Time Zone

You should decide in which time zone you count your days. Also I would prefer if you make the time zone explicit in yout code. If your system will be used in your own time zone only, the choice is easy, just make it explicit. For example:

```
    final LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Hong_Kong"));
```

Please fill in the relevant zone ID. This will also make sure the program works correctly even if one day it happens to run on a computer with an incorrect time zone setting. If your system is global, you may want to use UTC, for example:

```
    final LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

You will want to do similarly when saving the date when the user clicked Save so your data are consistent.

## 72 hours

Edit: I understand from your comment that you want to measure 3 days, that is, 72 hours, from the save time to determine whether the license has expired. For this a `LocalDate` does not give you enough information. It is only a date without a clock time, like May 26 2017 AD. There are some other options:

- `Instant` is a point in time (with nanosecond precision, even). This is the simple solution to make sure the expiration happens after 72 hours no matter if the user moves to another time zone.
- `ZonedDateTime` represents both a date and a time and a time zone, like 29 May 2017 AD 19:21:33.783 at offset GMT+08:00[Asia/Hong_Kong]. If you want to remind the user when the saved time was, a `ZonedDateTime` will you allow you to present that information with the time zone in which the save date was calculated.
- Finally `OffsetDateTime` would work too, but it doesn’t seem to give you much of the advantages of the two others, so I will not eloborate on this option.

Since an instant is the same in all time zones, you don’t specify a time zone when getting the current instant:

```
    final Instant currentDate = Instant.now();
```

Adding 3 days to an `Instant` is a little different `LocalDate`, but the rest of the logic is the same:

```
public static boolean hasDateExpired(int days, Instant savedDate, Instant currentDate) {
    boolean hasExpired = false;

    if(savedDate != null && currentDate != null) {
        /* has expired if the saved date plus the specified days is still before the current date (today) */
        if (savedDate.plus(days, ChronoUnit.DAYS).isBefore(currentDate)) {
            hasExpired = true;
        }       
    }

    return hasExpired;
}
```

The use of `ZonedDateTime`, on the other hand, goes exactly like `LocalDate` in the code:

```
    final ZonedDateTime currentDate = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Hong_Kong"));
```

If you want the current time zone setting from the JVM where the program runs:

```
    final ZonedDateTime currentDate = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Now if you declare `public static boolean hasDateExpired(int days, ZonedDateTime savedDate, ZonedDateTime currentDate)`, you may do as before:

```
        /* has expired if the saved date plus the specified days is still before the current date (today) */
        if (savedDate.plusDays(days).isBefore(currentDate)) {
            hasExpired = true;
        }
```

This will perform the correct comparison even if the two `ZonedDateTime` objects are in two different time zones. So no matter if the user travels to a different time zone, s/he will not get fewer nor more hours before the license expires.

Comment: Yes, this is the one important Answer posted so far. **Time zone is crucial** to determining the current date. So the expected/desired zone should be specified explicitly. Relying implicitly on the JVM`s current default time zone leads to unreliable behavior as that default may be unexpected and may even be changed *during* runtime(!) by any code in any app within that JVM.

Comment: Would this work if the user was to travel to different time zone not just located in Asia?

Comment: @ant2009 point is that most likely you want `currentDate` and `savedDate` calculated in the same time zone, or otherwise use a date that includes time zone. That should even work in the scenario that you move and test the date on a different client.

Answer (score 5):

The Answer by Hugo and the Answer by Ole V.V. Are both correct, and [the one by Ole V.V. is most important](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44208828/642706), as time zone is crucial to determine the current date.

## `Period`

Another useful class for this work is the [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class. This class represents a span of time unattached to the timeline as a number of years, months, and days.

Note that this class is *not* appropriate to representing the elapsed time needed for this Question because this representation is "chunked" as years, then months, and then any remaining days. So if `LocalDate.between( start , stop )` were used for an amount of several weeks, the result might be something like "two months and three days". Notice that this class does *not* implement the `Comparable` interface for this reason, as one pair of months cannot be said to be bigger or smaller than another pair unless we know which *specific* months are involved.

We *can* use this class to represent the two-day grace-period mentioned in the Question. Doing so makes our code more self-documenting. Better to pass around an object of this type than passing a mere integer.

```
Period grace = Period.ofDays( 2 ) ;

LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ).plusDays( grace ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 7 ) ;
```

We use [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) to calculate elapsed days.

```
int days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

## `Duration`

By the way, the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class is similar to `Period` in that it represents a span of time not attached to the timeline. But `Duration` represents a total of whole seconds plus a fractional second resolved in nanoseconds. From this you can calculate a number of generic 24-hour days (*not* date-based days), hours, minutes, seconds, and fractional second. Keep in mind that days are not always 24-hours long; here in the United States they currently may be 23, 24, or 25 hours long because of Daylight Saving Time.

This Question is about date-based days, not lumps of 24-hours. So the `Duration` class is not appropriate here.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I will have to keep with the org.threeten.bp.LocalDate as we have to support previous versions.

Comment: @ant2009 Then you should not have said you were using Java 8 in the first line of your Question.

Answer (score 2):

I think much better to use this:

```
Duration.between(currentDate.atStartOfDay(), savedDate.atStartOfDay()).toDays() > days;
```

`Duration` class placed in `java.time` package.

Comment: (A) You want `Period` here, not `Duration`, to count date-based days. (B) Why "much better"? Both approaches seem equally suited, to my mind.

Comment: @BasilBourque, (A) I want `Duration` as I mentioned above. (B) Much better because I can solve this task and this solution works well if I need get duration in another time unit. This is my subjective opinion based on my personal experience.

Comment: @BasilBourque, do you know how Period is calculating days? How it can be used in case described?

Comment: `Period` is explicitly built for `LocalDate`. Your "subjective opinion" is irrelevant if it fails to address the specific needs stated in the Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque, what my solution fails in the Question?

Answer (score 1):

**As this question is not getting "enough responses", I have added another answer:**

I have used "SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));" to set the timezone to UTC.  So there is no longer a timezone (all Date / time will be set to UTC).

**savedDate** is set to UTC.

**dateTimeNow** is also set to UTC, with the number of expired "days" (negative number) *added to dateTimeNow*.

A new Date **expiresDate** uses the long milliseconds from *dateTimeNow*

**Check** if savedDate.**before**(expiresDate)

---

```
package com.chocksaway;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class ExpiredDate {
    private static final long DAY_IN_MS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    private static boolean hasDateExpired(int days, java.util.Date savedDate) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUtc = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateFormatUtc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        // Local Date / time zone
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        // Date / time in UTC
        savedDate = dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatUtc.format(savedDate));

        Date dateTimeNow = dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatUtc.format(new Date()));

        long expires = dateTimeNow.getTime() + (DAY_IN_MS * days);

        Date expiresDate = new Date(expires);

        System.out.println("savedDate \t\t" + savedDate + "\nexpiresDate \t" + expiresDate);

        return savedDate.before(expiresDate);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);

        if (ExpiredDate.hasDateExpired(-2, cal.getTime())) {
            System.out.println("expired");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not expired");
        }

        System.out.print("\n");

        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -3);

        if (ExpiredDate.hasDateExpired(-2, cal.getTime())) {
            System.out.println("expired");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not expired");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Running this code gives the following output:

```
savedDate       Mon Jun 05 15:03:24 BST 2017
expiresDate     Sat Jun 03 15:03:24 BST 2017
not expired

savedDate       Fri Jun 02 15:03:24 BST 2017
expiresDate     Sat Jun 03 15:03:24 BST 2017
expired
```

**All** dates / times are UTC.  First is not expired.  Second is expired (savedDate is before expiresDate).

Answer (score 0):

**KISS**

```
public static boolean hasDateExpired(int days, java.util.Date savedDate) {
    long expires = savedDate().getTime() + (86_400_000L * days);
    return System.currentTimeMillis() > expires;
}
```

Works on old JRE's just fine. Date.getTime() gives milliseconds UTC, so timezone isn't even a factor. The magic 86'400'000 is the number of milliseconds in a day.

Instead of using java.util.Date you can simplify this further if you just use a long for savedTime.

Comment: This approach doesn't deal with timezones.

Comment: @chocksaway Doh. Thats what she said and thats what the OP wants, read his comments on the Q.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a simple utility class *ExpiredDate*, with a TimeZone (such as CET), expiredDate, expireDays, and differenceInHoursMillis.

I use java.util.Date, and Date.before(expiredDate):

To see if Date() *multiplied* by expiryDays *plus* (timezone difference *multiplied* by expiryDays) is before *expiredDate*.

Any date older than the expiredDate is "expired".

**A new Date is created by adding (i) + (ii):**

**(i)**. I use the number of milliseconds in a day to (DAY_IN_MS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) which is multiplied with the (number of) expireDays.

+

**(ii)**. To deal with a different TimeZone, I find the number of milliseconds between the Default timezone (for me BST), and the TimeZone (for example CET) passed into ExpiredDate.  For *CET, the difference is one hour*, which is 3600000 milliseconds.  This is multiplied by the (number of) expireDays.

*The new Date* is returned from **parseDate()**.

If the *new Date* is before the *expiredDate* -> set expired to True. 
    `dateTimeWithExpire.before(expiredDate);`

I have created 3 tests:

1. Set the expiry date 7 days, and expireDays = 3

   **Not expired**  (7 days is greater than 3 days)
2. Set the expiry date / time, and expireDays to 2 days

   **Not expired** - because the CET timezone adds two hours *(one hour per day)* to the dateTimeWithExpire
3. Set the expiry date 1 days, and expireDays = 2 (1 day is less than 2 days)

**expired is true**

---

```
package com.chocksaway;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class ExpiredDate {
    /**
     * milliseconds in a day
    */
    private static final long DAY_IN_MS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    private String timeZone;
    private Date expiredDate;
    private int expireDays;
    private int differenceInHoursMillis;

    /**
     *
     * @param timeZone - valid timezone
     * @param expiredDate - the fixed date for expiry
     * @param expireDays - the number of days to expire
    */
    private ExpiredDate(String timeZone, Date expiredDate, int expireDays) {
        this.expiredDate = expiredDate;
        this.expireDays = expireDays;
        this.timeZone = timeZone;

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int zoneOffset =   TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone).getOffset(currentTime);
        int defaultOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(currentTime);

        /**
         * Example:
         *     TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone) is BST
         *     timeZone is CET
         *
         *     There is one hours difference, which is 3600000 milliseconds
         *
         */

        this.differenceInHoursMillis = (zoneOffset - defaultOffset);
    }


    /**
     *
     * Subtract a number of expire days from the date
     *
     * @param dateTimeNow - the date and time now
     * @return - the date and time minus the number of expired days
     *           + (difference in hours for timezone * expiryDays)
     *
     */
    private Date parseDate(Date dateTimeNow) {
        return new Date(dateTimeNow.getTime() - (expireDays * DAY_IN_MS) + (this.differenceInHoursMillis * expireDays));
    }


    private boolean hasDateExpired(Date currentDate) {
        Date dateTimeWithExpire = parseDate(currentDate);

        return dateTimeWithExpire.before(expiredDate);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        /* Set the expiry date 7 days, and expireDays = 3
        *
        * Not expired
        */

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);

        ExpiredDate expired = new ExpiredDate("CET", cal.getTime(), 3);

        Date dateTimeNow = new Date();

        if (expired.hasDateExpired(dateTimeNow)) {
            System.out.println("expired");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT expired");

        }

        /* Set the expiry date / time, and expireDays to 2 days
         *  Not expired - because the CET timezone adds two hours to the dateTimeWithExpire
        */


        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);

        expired = new ExpiredDate("CET", cal.getTime(), 2);

        dateTimeNow = new Date();

        if (expired.hasDateExpired(dateTimeNow)) {
            System.out.println("expired");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT expired");

        }

        /* Set the expiry date 1 days, and expireDays = 2
        *
        * expired
        */

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

        expired = new ExpiredDate("CET", cal.getTime(), 2);

        dateTimeNow = new Date();

        if (expired.hasDateExpired(dateTimeNow)) {
            System.out.println("expired");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT expired");

        }

     } 
 }
```